# transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority,address LimitRanger: missing port in address

Tags: certificate, authorization, kube-apiserver

when i start a kube-apiserver ,the log shows that

```
W0225 19:40:59.585020   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Node --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --token-auth-file=/opt/kubernetes/cfg/token.csv --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 --kubelet-client-certificate=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server.pem --kubelet-client-key=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server-key.pem --tls-cert-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server.pem --tls-private-key-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server-key.pem --client-ca-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem --etcd-cafile=/opt/etcd/ssl/ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/opt/etcd/ssl/server.pem --etcd-keyfile=/opt/etcd/ssl/server-key.pem --audit-log-maxage=30 --audit-log-maxbackup=3 --audit-log-maxsize=100 --audit-log-path=/opt/kubernetes/logs/k8s-audit.log  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address Node --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --token-auth-file=/opt/kubernetes/cfg/token.csv --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 --kubelet-client-certificate=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server.pem --kubelet-client-key=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server-key.pem --tls-cert-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server.pem --tls-private-key-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/server-key.pem --client-ca-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/opt/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem --etcd-cafile=/opt/etcd/ssl/ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/opt/etcd/ssl/server.pem --etcd-keyfile=/opt/etcd/ssl/server-key.pem --audit-log-maxage=30 --audit-log-maxbackup=3 --audit-log-maxsize=100 --audit-log-path=/opt/kubernetes/logs/k8s-audit.log: missing port in address". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.585048   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {ServiceAccount  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address ServiceAccount: missing port in address". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.585236   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {NodeRestriction --authorization-mode=RBAC  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address NodeRestriction --authorization-mode=RBAC: missing port in address". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.585238   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://10.215.15.15:2379 --bind-address=10.215.7.163 --secure-port=6443 --advertise-address=10.215.7.163 --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/24 --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address https://10.215.15.15:2379 --bind-address=10.215.7.163 --secure-port=6443 --advertise-address=10.215.7.163 --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/24 --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.585377   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {LimitRanger  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address LimitRanger: missing port in address". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.675507   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://10.215.7.163:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:40:59.675765   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://10.215.7.25:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...
W0225 19:41:00.567994   13807 clientconn.go:1208] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {LimitRanger  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address LimitRanger: missing port in address". Reconnecting...
```

i had upgrade my cfssl to v1.4.1 and rebuild the pem file,and restart my kube-apiserver.but still show that error log.